# How to override Policy setting for specific OU

Tags: group-policy, terminal-server, rds

I have an issue applying a GPO for an OU.
The case is that i have a RDS server that various users connect to it...
For the users i have the policy "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session" Enabled....so that each user can only have 1 session...
The problem is that i need for some users to have this setting lifted so that they can have more than one session...
I created a new OU and moved these users and created an OU that sets Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session --> disabled....  but no matter what i can get it applied.. as long the Restriction is ON all the users have only one(1) session....any ideas..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a Computer setting, not a User setting. You can't filter it based on the user. It applies to all users logging onto that RDS server.

Comment: That's true but is there any way to override it ?

Comment: No. It's a computer setting. It applies to all users who log on to that RDS server. You can't override a Computer setting based on the user. - http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2494

Comment: So there absolutely no way to have this specific behavior...too bad...i have to rethink my strategy....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, the setting to restrict RD users to a single session is computer specific. Your best option to relax this for a group of users is to add an additional RD Session Host to the farm and only allow the 'special' users permission to connect to it. Then apply a new GPO to the new server which modifies the session connection limit. To do that, just remove the 'apply group policy' permission for authenticated users and grant it only to the computers that need the policy (or a group containing the computer objects). Let me know if you have any questions.